# OAuth providers that return an email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, oauth-2.0

I'm just getting started setting up OAuth authentication in Ruby on Rails using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and so far have successfully setup Yahoo, Google and Facebook sign-in.

My goal is to provide one-click registration, so I need the providers to return an email address and was disappointed to learn that Twitter and LinkedIn do not return an email address. I've seen tutorials for "completing the registration process", but for my site that would defeat the purpose of one-click registration.

Are there any other OAuth providers that return an email address besides the ones previously mentioned that can be used for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: I actually have no idea, but here's a [list](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies) of all the oauth providers supported by omniauth. To tell you the truth, those 3 providers should cover all your needs. For instance, StackOverflow only uses those 3. More would be overkill, in my opinion. But if you really want to add more oauth providers, just investigate that list.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, too many more would be overkill.  Windows Live ID is the only one on that list that I think would be worth adding and it looks like that returns an email address.

Answer (score 0):

By the way Google's OAuth 2.0 authentication endpoints does return the email address if you request it, along with other useful data such as the user's picture, first and last name, birthday etc...

The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn's API does provide email ID if you ask for it. As far as I know, only Twitter doesnt send the email ID. 
Yes, it is indeed a pain in the neck. I had to create a separate 'checkpoint' flow for a Twitter user's first-time login to my app and ask for the email ID.